# How to use Quarkus gRPC extension with Gradle?

Tags: java, grpc, code-generation, quarkus, quarkus-grpc

According to [the Quarkus gRPC documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-getting-started), there has to be `generate-code` goal enabled for the `quarkus-maven-plugin`. However, I have not found if the corresponding functionality is implemented for the Quarkus Gradle plugin.

**Question:** How to build a Quarkus gRPC project with Gradle?

Comment: Sasha Shpota were you able configure Quarkus gRPC with Gradle?

Comment: @Shb yes, here is an example of a project which I created to reproduce a bug in Quarkus, but it is a valid Gradle project with gRPC https://github.com/shpota/quarkus-grpc-alpine-issue. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Gradle there is no need to add another goal/task to the build configuration. The Quarkus Gradle plugin handles it itself.